# jQuery insertAfter() not working as expected

Tags: jquery, insertafter

I'm trying to take #filters and all of it's contents and insert it after the  in the following structure:

```
<div id = "top-level">

  <div id = "sub-level-1">
    <div class = "another-level">
      <div class = "last-level">
        <nav class = "nav-menu"></nav>
        <!-- insert #filters here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <aside>
    <div id = "filters"> 
      <div id = "filters-form">
        <div class = "more-contents"></div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  <aside>

</div>
```

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work as expected. It can't seem to "find" .nav-menu and insert it after, though I'm able to insert it after higher level elements.

```
// this works
var filters = $("#filters");
filters.insertAfter("#sub-level-1");

// doesn't work
var filters = $("#filters");
filters.insertAfter(".nav-menu");
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add a comment: `<!--...-->`  to the exact location where you want `$('#filters')` moved to?

Answer (score 0):

I reworked it and got it to work.  Keep in mind I put in some text just so I can inspect the elements easily.

```js
var filters = $("#filters");
filters.insertAfter(".nav-menu");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "top-level">
  <div id = "sub-level-1">
    <div class = "another-level">
      <div class = "last-level">
        <nav class = "nav-menu">bbb</nav>
        <!-- insert #filters here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <aside>
    <div id = "filters"> 
      <div id = "filters-form">
        <div class = "more-contents">aaa</div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </aside>
</div>
```

One edit I did was that your aside didn't have a closing tag, just two opening tags, so I fixed that.

Comment: It looks like your jQuery is identical to mine?

Comment: It is, except I only used the statements you said weren't working, not the one you said that did work.  You don't have those two examples next to each other like that in your code, right?  The only other thing I did was to your HTML that I commented on above.

Comment: Hmm..I must have recreated the directory structure from memory incorrectly. This definitely wasn't working today at work and I don't have them next to each other like that in the code.

Comment: OK, if it's still a problem when you're back at work, repost it and hopefully you will get an answer that will solve it.

Comment: Oh, and if you want me to delete this, let me know.

Comment: Thanks,  I'm going to compare it in the morning!